# SSL error in SugarCRM in localhost

Tags: php, ssl, sugarcrm

I did install SugarCRM professional on one of the public IP address and configured that which works smoothly in this following link

http://66.240.55.100/fs

I tried to copy the files and database as it is to my local system which could be accessed like this link

http://localhost/fs/index.php[image]

When I add the exception and proceed, I see following error message
[image]

I deleted the cache directory and tried, but no luck.
My question is,
 Why its asking SSL, how to disable it in localhost or any other issues exist in the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the settings on .htaccess file. Like redirecting to other files and/or https URL. It should fix the issue.

Comment: I will definately not recommend deleting the .htaccess file. E.g. at the moment I have access to all your uploaded files. I recommend making the change Sneha suggested.